# Select IDs that match all items on table

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

So I have a table called *Mroom* which looks something like this:

```
CREATE Mroom(ID_ROOM NUMBER(3), CHAR_NAME NVARCHAR2(30), CHAR_VALUE NUMBER(20));
```

The contents of the table are something like:

> 1; air-conditioner; 1
>
> 1; pool; 2
>
> 2; pool; 1

Which would mean that the room with the *ID* 1 has 1 air-conditioner and 2 pools. And the room with the *ID* 2 has one pool.
I've also created a table of a datatype, that I've called *c_chars*:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE c_chars FORCE IS OBJECT (CHAR VARCHAR2(20), VALUE NUMBER(30));
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE tab_chars FORCE IS TABLE OF c_chars;
/
```

And I need to know if for example if there are any rooms that have at least 1 air-conditioner and a pool. My current code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE thisRoomOK(v_carateristicas IN tab_chars, lista OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
IS BEGIN
OPEN lista FOR SELECT MRoom.ID_ROOM
FROM Mroom, TABLE(v_carateristicas) v_carateristicas
WHERE Mroom.CHAR_NAME = v_carateristicas.CHAR
AND Mroom.VALUE >= v_carateristicas.VALUE
GROUP BY Mroom.ID_ROOM
ORDER BY getSalas.Mroom.ID_ROOM;
END;
/
```

The problem is if I ask for the rooms that have at least one air-conditioner and a pool. It will return me both rooms, because the rrom 2 has a pool (it works like an **OR**, but I'd like it to work like and **AND**).

#### Edit 1:

If possible, I'd like to receive answers that changes the procedure, but not the tables, altough all answers are welcome!

#### Edit 2:

The code above is a simplification, this is the full code:

**Object definition:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE c_valor FORCE IS OBJECT (CARATERISTICA VARCHAR2(20), VALOR NUMBER(30));
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE tabc_valor FORCE IS TABLE OF c_valor;
/
```

**Procedure:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE getSalas_Carateristicas(v_carateristicas IN tabc_valor, lista OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
IS BEGIN
OPEN lista FOR SELECT getSalas.ID_SALA
FROM getSalas, TABLE(v_carateristicas) v_carateristicas
WHERE getSalas.NOME_CARATERISTICA = v_carateristicas.CARATERISTICA
AND getSalas.VALOR >= v_carateristicas.VALOR
GROUP BY getSalas.ID_SALA
ORDER BY getSalas.ID_SALA;
END;
/
```

**Procedure altered according to @XING's sugestion:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE getSalas_Carateristicas(v_carateristicas IN tabc_valor, lista OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
IS BEGIN
OPEN lista FOR SELECT getSalas.ID_SALA
FROM getSalas
INNER JOIN TABLE(v_carateristicas) v_carateristicas ON getSalas.NOME_CARATERISTICA = v_carateristicas.CARATERISTICA
AND getSalas.VALOR >= v_carateristicas.VALOR
GROUP BY getSalas.ID_SALA
ORDER BY getSalas.ID_SALA;
END;
/
```

Comment: It seems you need a `having` clause after `group by` - if you are looking for two characteristics (A/C and pool), you want `having count(*) = 2`. That is, there will be two rows selected for that room: one because it has at least the required number of A/C's and the second because it has at least the required number of pools. In general, `2` should be the count of characteristics (? "chars") in `tab_chars`.

Comment: @mathguy. Putting having will not solve the problem. The problem depends on how OP ask for the room. What all values he is passing.

Comment: @mathguy, what do you mean?

Comment: @Safirah ..isnt your problem solved, Did you tried the way i said.

Comment: @XING, yes I've tried and it did not work, http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134070/discussion-between-safirah-and-xing

Comment: Did you change your object definition as well ? Show the whole code what you did. Coz it should had worked if you would had done it correctly as i showed you

Comment: Also show how are you executing it.

Comment: I'm using a web-application (in jsp) to execute it, but I believe I'm executing the procedure right, since the other procedures are functioning correctly

Answer (score 0):

I guess the issue is with the way you ask for a room. See below demo and explaination inline.

Proc:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE T541682.c_chars FORCE IS OBJECT (v_CHAR VARCHAR2(20), v_VALUE NUMBER(30));
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE T541682.tab_chars FORCE IS TABLE OF c_chars;

/
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE T541682.thisRoomOK (
       v_carateristicas      IN     tab_chars,
       lista                 OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
    IS
    BEGIN
       OPEN lista FOR
            SELECT MRoom.ID_ROOM
              FROM Mroom 
              inner join TABLE (v_carateristicas) v_carateristicas
              ON     Mroom.CHAR_NAME = v_carateristicas.v_CHAR
             AND     Mroom.CHAR_VALUE = v_carateristicas.v_VALUE
          GROUP BY Mroom.ID_ROOM     
          ORDER BY Mroom.ID_ROOM;



END;
/


declare

var tab_chars :=tab_chars();

type var1 is table of MRoom.ID_ROOM%type index by pls_integer;

var_out var1;

x sys_refcursor;

begin

 var.extend(3);

 -- This is the way i populate my object for which i want to match with the table. Am sure you are passing all rows same as your table hence its getting the all the rows.

 var(1) := c_chars('air-conditioner',1);
 var(2) := c_chars('pool',2);

 -- Must be populating the third row as well. And as per your query both rows wil be picked up if you populate the object .

 --var(3) := c_chars('pool',1);

 -- Calling your procedure 

 thisRoomOK(v_carateristicas => var,lista => x);

 fetch x bulk collect into var_out ;

 --- displaying number of room
 for i in 1..var_out.count
  loop
    dbms_output.put_line('Room Number - '||var_out(i));
  end loop;  

 ---passing the sys_refcursor result to another procedure

  proc1(var_out);

end;
```

Output:

```
SQL> /
Room Number - 1

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: But would that work if several rooms match the characteristics? For example if I ask for a room with A/C, would 2 rooms show up? And I don't want an `dbms_ouput` because another procedure is gonna use the output values

Comment: No..it wont show 2 room coz your table `Mroom` doesnot have 2 rooms with ac. It will act as a table matching with another table on passed condition.  I used dbms_ouput to give you can example.. You can use it your way. You can try and see if that works or not

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, I meant a pool.

Comment: You are passing 2 values and using it in query. If both the conditions are satisfied then only you will get row. So in the case shown it will return only one. Give a try and let me know

Comment: I will, but could you give me some suggestions on how to transform this so that the procedure returns a cursor?

Comment: Your procedure is already returning a cursor. I just executed the content of your  sys_refcursor and displayed it. You can pass `var_out` as `in `paramter to another procedure. See my edit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134070/discussion-between-safirah-and-xing).